# MySQL Error Code 1452 Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql

Using these tables

```
CREATE TABLE people(
  idPeople INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,     
  name VARCHAR(100),     
  email VARCHAR(100),     
  PRIMARY KEY(idPeople)
);

CREATE TABLE country_details (  
  idCountry INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
  country VARCHAR(45)
);

CREATE TABLE registration_details(  
  idRegistration INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
  register_date DATETIME NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE registration(  
  idRegistration INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
  idPeople INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,     
  idCountry INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,    
  register_date_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  email VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  register_date VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
  country VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',    
  FOREIGN KEY(idCountry) REFERENCES country_details(idCountry),     
  FOREIGN KEY(register_date_id) REFERENCES 
  registration_details(register_date_id), 
  FOREIGN KEY(idPeople) REFERENCES people(idPeople)
);
```

I am getting the error:

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`peopledb`.`registration`, CONSTRAINT `registration_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idCountry`) REFERENCES `country_details` (`idCountry`))

Anyone know what could be happening?

Comment: Why have you tagged SQL Server?

Comment: Oh, is this not SQL Server related? If not I apologize.

Comment: As the tag. [tag:sql-server] tells you, *"Microsoft SQL Server is a relational database management system (RDBMS)."* and ***"Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.)."*** MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products.

Answer (score 1):

[Foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) ensure that a parent table (in your case country_details) holds a value that is replicated in the child table (registration).

What's happening is that you're trying to input data into registration that attempts to reference a country id that doesn't exist in the country_details table.